# Rspec `eq` vs `eql` in `expect` tests

Tags: ruby, rspec

What is the difference between using `eq` and `eql` in rspec tests? Is there a difference between:

```
it "adds the correct information to entries" do
  # book = AddressBook.new # => Replaced by line 4
  book.add_entry('Ada Lovelace', '010.012.1815', 'augusta.king@lovelace.com')
  new_entry = book.entries[0]

  expect(new_entry.name).to eq('Ada Lovelace')
  expect(new_entry.phone_number).to eq('010.012.1815')
  expect(new_entry.email).to eq('augusta.king@lovelace.com')
end
```

and:

```
it "adds the correct information to entries" do
  # book = AddressBook.new # => Replaced by line 4
  book.add_entry('Ada Lovelace', '010.012.1815', 'augusta.king@lovelace.com')
  new_entry = book.entries[0]

  expect(new_entry.name).to eql('Ada Lovelace')
  expect(new_entry.phone_number).to eql('010.012.1815')
  expect(new_entry.email).to eql('augusta.king@lovelace.com')
end
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There are subtle differences here, based on the type of equality being used in the comparison.

From the Rpsec docs:

```
Ruby exposes several different methods for handling equality:

a.equal?(b) # object identity - a and b refer to the same object
a.eql?(b) # object equivalence - a and b have the same value
a == b # object equivalence - a and b have the same value with type conversions]
```

`eq` uses the `==` operator for comparison, and `eql` ignores type conversions.

Comment: Would a type conversion mean it is looking for the objects or things being compared to be the same type of object?

Comment: @austinthesing it means that `42.0 == 42` produces `true` and `42.0.eql? 42` produces `false`.

Comment: It is to be noted that the type is not converted from a string. So if you will compare `"1" == 1`, it will always return `false`

Answer (score 40):

The differences are subtle.`eq` is the same [as the ruby implementation](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers.rb#L564) of `==`. On the other hand `eql` is the same as the [ruby implementation](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers.rb#L564) of `eql?`.

`eq` checks object equivalence and will type cast to convert different object to the same type.

Two objects are equivalent if they are of the same class and have the same value but they are not necessarily the same object in memory.

```
expect(:my_symbol).to eq(:my_symbol)
# passes, both are identical.
expect('my string').to eq('my string')
# passes, objects are equivalent 
expect(5).to eq(5.0)
# passes, Objects are not equivalent but was type cast to same object type.
```

`eql` checks object equivalence and does not try type casting.

```
expect(:my_symbol).to eql(:my_symbol)
# passes, both are identical.
expect('my string').to eql('my string')
# passes, objects are equivalent but not identical 
expect(5).to eql(5.0)
# fails, Objects are not equivalence, did not try to type cast
```

`equal` checks object identity.
Two object are identical if they are the same object meaning they have same object id (share the same address in memory).

```
expect(:my_symbol).to equal(:my_symbol)
# passes, both are identical.
expect('my string').to equal('my string')
# fails, objects are equivalent but not identical
expect(5).to equal(5.0)
# fails, objects are not equivalent and not identical
```

Comment: My silly mnemonic for this is the longer the method name the stricter the comparison: `eq` < `eql` < `equal`