# Rails Rspec integer equals string ("1" == 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, integer, comparator

How, in rspec, do you compare the value of something while ignoring the type?

```
Failure/Error: expect(variable).to eql model.id

  expected: 1234
       got: "1234"

  (compared using eql?)
```

I've tried `eq` (which compares using `==`) and `eql` (which compares using `eql?`)... I've also read https://stackoverflow.com/a/32926980/224707.

How do I make rspec consider those two values equal?

Comment: Your issue is not clear. Define the concept of "compare the value of something while ignoring the type". According to your idea, is the string "A" equal to 1 because the letter "A" appears exactly once in it?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to write `expect(variable).to eql model.id.to_s`?

Comment: You can't ignore the type while comparing equality because `"1"` is not equal to `1`. You can either cast your `variable` to `integer` or the `model.id` to `String`.

Comment: `expect(variable.to_i).to eql model.id`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instances of different classes cannot be equal.

You need to convert them so they become instances of the same Class :

```
"1234" == 1234
#=> false
"1234".to_i == 1234
#=> true
1234.to_s == "1234"
#=> true
```

So in your example :

```
expect(variable.to_i).to eql model.id
# or less logical :
expect(variable).to eql model.id.to_s
```

Answer (score 3):

`==` checks both instance type and value to be same so you need to convert them to be same

Change it to either of one

```
expect(variable.to_i).to eql model.id
```

or

```
expect(variable).to eql model.id.to_s
```

Comment: Thanks @Deepak - Just beaten to the first answer by 1 minute ;)